# 360 video editor for linux

Tags: video-editor

I am using ubuntu 16, but am curious if there exists a 360 video editor (meaning can edit 360 degree videos) that can be used on linux of any distro.

Obviously, it would be amazing if there was something that was free, but I am just curious at this point what my options are (if any)

Comment: Any news over the last 15 months...?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as of late 2016, there are very few VR video editors, if none.

The closest I can think of is Blender- you can create 360 degree videos and models in Blender. I can't speak as to its efficacy, however.

Comment: I was afraid of that.  I had looked around online and wasn't able to find much, which is why i asked.  But it sounds like your probably right